# Where to deploy external resources/files?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.4

within my Qt5 application a file ":items/cube.obj" is accessed (.obj is a 3D format and this comes from a piece of example code).

Where within my project/Qt installation path do I have to deploy this file "cube.obj" to let it work with this funny path name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html):

> By default, resources are accessible in the application under the same
>   file name as they have in the source tree, with a :/ prefix, or by a
>   URL with a qrc scheme.

Note: forward slash in `:/`.

1. If you don't use `prefix` in `.qrc`, it would be in `items` directory next to `.pro`:

   ```
   /path/to/project/myproject.pro
   /path/to/project/items/cube.obj
   ```

   In this case root prefix is used.
2. If using non-root `prefix`, `.qrc` could be:

   ```
   <qresource prefix="/items">
       <file>cube.obj</file>
   </qresource>
   ```

   and files structure:

   ```
   /path/to/project/myproject.pro
   /path/to/project/cube.obj
   ```
3. Using `alias`:

   ```
   <qresource prefix="/items">
       <file alias="cube.obj">items/cube.obj</file>
   </qresource>
   ```

   and files structure:

   ```
   /path/to/project/myproject.pro
   /path/to/project/items/cube.obj
   ```